# Is utime.ticks_diff() safe to run in a ISR?

Tags: interrupt, micropython

I need to use `utime.ticks_diff()` in a ISR code. Do you think it is ISR-safe ? They say that in a ISR you should not use floating point. The code of `ticks_diff()` is this:

```
def ticks_diff(a, b):
    return ((a - b + MICROPY_PY_UTIME_TICKS_PERIOD // 2) & (MICROPY_PY_UTIME_TICKS_PERIOD - 1)) - MICROPY_PY_UTIME_TICKS_PERIOD // 2
```

It has some divisions, but I'm not sure if floating point is used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MicroPython "[implements Python 3.4 and some select features of Python 3.5 and above](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/genrst/index.html)".

The `//` operator is 'floor division' [(Python 3.4 docs)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), and from there

> floor division of integers results in an integer

The list of [MicroPython differences from CPython](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/genrst/index.html) doesn't say that `//` works any differently in MicroPython than in CPython.

So you should be safe to use this method - but why not try it?

Comment: I try it, and it works. But I wanted to be sure... I am new to Python and they say to not use floating point in in ISRs...